# "yell at" vs "nag at" vs "scold" vs "reprimand" vs "tell off" differences?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

What are the differences among the words mentioned above?
To me "yell at" and "nag at" are informal way to say that someone disapproves something to someone else, with the difference that "yell at" involves the action of actually "yelling" while the other one doesn't necessarily. "Scold" as far as I've understood means the same thing (disapprove something) but it is old fashion. "Reprimand" never heard of it, but Cambridge dictionary suggests that could mean the same thing (in a formal context maybe?).

Like for example, a colleague of mine could be told by my boss that he has done something wrong. If I had to tell the story to a close friend of mine I would say "The boss yelled at X" (because maybe he actually yelled), while to a generic random colleague Y I would say "The boss reprimanded X" (because formally it was what happened, and I don't want to tell him how rude my boss was). "Tell off" apparently is used to express the same thing but in a parenting situation maybe.

Am I wrong? If yes, could you clarify the differences?

Comment: Why the down-vote out of curiosity?

Comment: I think there are lots of angry and resentful people who like to downvote just because they can. I upvoted because I think this is a good question, and most of the time I prefer to debate instead of giving a downvote, which is how a true Christian would proceed.

Answer (score 2):

There are very many ways to disapprove of someone, ranging from a mild frown to shooting him dead.

If you **[yell](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yell)** or **[shout](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shout)** at someone, or **[scold](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scold)** him, you're mightily annoyed, angry and don't care to conceal it. Most of the times it's a pretty loud business.

If you **[nag](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nag)** someone - a way subtler method - you keep pestering him with cutting remarks until he gives up and does what you want (or blows up). Note that nagging doesn't necessarily imply disapproval: it can be done also out of sheer nastiness or naughtiness.

If you **[reprimand](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reprimand)** someone, you're his boss and you're telling him (not necessarily calmly) that he shouldn't have done what he did. This doesn't need to be hot; on the contrary it can be extremely and unpleasantly cold (which is way worse).

**[Telling](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell-sb-off?q=tell%20off)** someone **[off](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell-sb-off?q=tell%20off)** is akin to reprimanding him, just less businesslike.

Conciseness and readability demand that I restrict myself to masculine pronouns, but of course the above abused *he* may as well be a *she*. I hope no lady will feel wronged because of that.